# How to detect multiple strings in another vector of strings

Tags: r

I need to output a logical indicating which strings match and which don't.

```
words<-c("happy","sad") 
all_words<-c("happy","tragic","sad","angry","mad","laugh","happy")
```

Note: There are repeats!

By using the `stringr` package I can almost reach the result that I want but not exactly.

```
> str_detect(all_words,fixed(words))
TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Is almost correct, except the third index should be showing up as a `TRUE`, since the word sad is present in the `all_words` vector.

The output should look like:

```
 TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need:

```
all_words %in% words
```

From `help("%in%")`:

> %in% is a more intuitive interface as a binary operator, which returns
>   a logical vector indicating if there is a match or not for its left
>   operand.

Basically for each element in the first vector, it checks if there's a match in the left hand vector.

Comment: Hi can you please explain how %in% works. It did the job.

Answer (score 1):

```
words<-c("happy","sad") 
all_words<-c("happy","tragic","sad","angry","mad","laugh","happy")
```

all you need is:

```
all_words %in% words
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```